# Guard running only the first watcher that matches

Tags: ruby, guard

Is there a way to prevent Guard to run all the watchers that match a file structure but only the first one?

I basically need to instantiate a different object if the file copied in my root folder has a specific structure or not. For instance, if the file name matches `\d{2}-\d{6}_\d{5}_\d+_\d+.csv` I need to instances object A while for all the other `.cvs` files object B.

As first attempt I was trying to use negative lookbehind but due to lookbehind limitations it looks like I cannot do that.
So, now I'm trying to force Guard to execute only the first watcher that matches.

My Guardfile looks like

```
guard :my_csv_files do
  watch(%r{^\d{2}-\d{6}_\d{5}_\d+_\d+.csv$})
end

guard :others_csv_files do
   watch(%r{^.+.csv$})
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been available for a while, but was never documented. (Until today).

There's a `:first_match` option, which does exactly what you want:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-DSL---Configuring-Guard#guard